# Syntax error "," expected but i can't find it (C# Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private int skor 0;
```

it says "syntax error "," expected" and i cant figure out why i am very new at unity sorry if it has a very obvious answer.

Comment: problem is solved thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing assignment operator `=` in your `skor` declaration:

```
private int skor = 0;
```